# Is it possible to copy and update a python dictionary in a single chained expression?

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider the following:

```
x = {1:2}
y = x.copy() # returns a new dictionary
y = x.copy().update({2:3}) # returns None
y = x.copy()[2] = 3 # invalid syntax
```

Given that none of the above work, is there a way to chain a command to `Dict.copy()` to copy and update a dictionary in a single command?

Comment: You can of course create your own functions for this (like updating and returning the new dictionary), but I guess that's beside your point.  I guess that this is as it is is a design decision to enforce that updating a dict needs to be an own iterative step in order to make the cost of this procedure visible.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: Function argument to a decortator in a test suite... and personal curiousity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`dict()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) to create a copy and add keyword arguments; use `**{...}` to add arbitrary keys that are not Python identifiers:

```
y = dict(x, **{2: 3})
```

For string keys that happen to be valid Python identifiers (start with a letter, contain only letters and digits and underscores), use keyword arguments to `dict()`:

```
y = dict(x, foo_bar='spam_eggs')
```

You can combine the two styles, and add more keys:

```
y = dict(x, foo='spam', bar='eggs', **{2: 3, 42: 81})
```

Demo:

```
>>> x = {1: 2}
>>> dict(x, **{2: 3})
{1: 2, 2: 3}
>>> dict(x, foo_bar='spam_eggs')
{1: 2, 'foo_bar': 'spam_eggs'}
>>> dict(x, foo='spam', bar='eggs', **{2: 3, 42: 81})
{1: 2, 2: 3, 'foo': 'spam', 'bar': 'eggs', 42: 81}
>>> x  # not changed, copies were made
{1: 2}
```

Comment: This is a great answer!!  I did not know you could do this!  I'd give two upvotes if I could.  :)

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2, you can use:

```
y = dict(x.items()+{2:3}.items())
```

or:

```
y = dict(x.items()+[(2, 3)])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use dict comprehension:

```
y = {
    k:v
    for dct in ( x, {2:3} )
    for k,v in dct.items()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this example is that you are treating "x.copy()" as if it is the same instance each time you use it, but it is not.  Every call to "x.copy()" creates a new copy of "x".

```
x = {1:2}
y = x.copy() # first new copy, saved as "y"
y = x.copy().update({2:3}) # a second new copy, which is not saved because the 
                           # result of the update() method (which is None) is saved
y = x.copy()[2] = 3 # A third new copy is created, but it's the same as the
                    # original x, and has no key value of "2"
```

I tried to come up with a one liner using lambda functions, but I think it would be much uglier than just saying

```
y = x.copy(); y.update({2:3})
```